# Make my view able to accept child views in xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I have write my own view Bar, which extends `LinearLayout`. My bar has two places for add buttons or other view. Now I add items to my Bar using code, like:

`bar.addItemToLeft(view);` or
    `bar.addItemToRight(view);`

**I would like to make my Bar able to accept childs view in xml like `LinearLayout`.**

For example:

```
<com.my.ui.Bar
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.my.ui.BarLeft
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <View/> <View/> <View/>

        </com.my.ui.BarLeft>

         <com.my.ui.BarRight
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <View/> <View/> <View/>

        </com.my.ui.BarLeft>

</com.my.ui.Bar>
```

Is it possiable to do?

PS:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bar left and right bar must extend a ViewGroup (LinearLayout, relativeLayout) to be able to accpet childs.

regards,
Aqif Hamid

Comment: Then you must be able to add controls to your layout the same way you do with your LinearLayouts.

Comment: Please, look at image top. There is shown places, which I want to add items to.